# angularjs factory for html5 websockets with init of socket with url passed

Tags: angularjs, sockets, websocket

How to create a AngularJS factory for HTML5 WebSockets?

My server serves websocket connections on multiple paths as such:

```
ws://192.168.225.59:8080/chat/
ws://192.168.225.59:8080/notif/
ws://192.168.225.59:8080/something/
```

I would like to have a factory `Socket` that could accept any path from the above and open a websocket connection.

My approach:

`socket.service.js`

```
angular.
  module('core.socket').
  factory('Socket', [function() {
      var stack = [];
      var onmessageDefer;
      var self = this;

      var socket = {
          ws: new WebSocket("ws://192.168.225.59:8080/"),
          send: function(data) {
              data = JSON.stringify(data);
              if (socket.ws.readyState == 1) {
                  socket.ws.send(data);
              } else {
                  stack.push(data);
              }
          },
          onmessage: function(callback) {
              if (socket.ws.readyState == 1) {
                  socket.ws.onmessage = callback;
              } else {
                  onmessageDefer = callback;
              }
          }
      };

      socket.init = function(url){
        socket.ws.close();
        socket.ws = new WebSocket(url);
      }
      socket.ws.onopen = function(event) {
          for (i in stack) {
              socket.ws.send(stack[i]);
          }
          stack = [];
          if (onmessageDefer) {
              socket.ws.onmessage = onmessageDefer;
              onmessageDefer = null;
          }
      };
      return socket;
  }]);
```

Here I would call `Socket.init("ws://192.168.225.59:8080/something/")` from my controller, which disconnects from the existing connection and establishes this new connection. But this approach somehow blocks from receiving messages.

Any help?